Graphical artifacts appearing on translucent lines in plots
I am trying to plot lines with some translucent behavior, for which I set the opacity to some number in PlotStyle. However, this gives me random squares in the plot that are darker than the rest. How can I force this behavior to go away? I am on Mathematica 14.0. A minimum working example is the following
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4},PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]]

which produces the attached plot, with the square visible near x==1.


fyi, I do not see this on windows 10 using V 14

Interesting - I am on V14 on a Macbook Pro.

I can replicate this on Macbook / v14 and it looks like a bug; I would report it to Wolfram.

I can NOT replicate that in Wolfram Cloud, but I have a thought to share: That looks like the plot trace is internally divided into two segments. I have seen that as an annoying feature when exporting plots as vector graphics formats like SVG or PDF, where for no real reason, plot traces are not part of a single object but an arbitrary set of ungrouped elements.  Does anybody have insights on the internal representation of plots that could justify that division? (BTW, FullGraphics, which could have given some insight, is still broken in V14)

In FullForm of your plot do you see more than one line?

I do not see more than one line with FullForm.

I thought this came up before...Can anyone find it?

This is a long-standing issue that I remember reporting before. It was fixed at one point then it was broken again.

Ugh ... I didn't realize that I had single-vote duplicate closing rights for this tag ...

We are discussing here, AFAIK for the first time, the underlying cause. i.e. internally the trace is represented by multiple segments. I think we should keep this question open. Probably it's best to edit the title to be more descriptive of the causing issue instead of closing it.

@rhemans, the "broken to many pieces" is mentioned in the accepted answer by Szabolcs. Also, the other answer there gives the official workaround from WRI (CapForm), so this question seems like a very clear duplicate to me ...

@Domen touché, that escaped me, thanks for pointing it out. Probably then, the only aspect that could save this is the attempt to actually join the segments.

CapForm[] fixes it on my Mac:
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]]



(+1) Is it correct to say that you are avoiding the overlapping region by removing the end caps of the lines instead of joining the multiple lines?

Does not work in all circumstances, when the function has large slope, for example Plot[ArcTan[20 x], {x, -10, 10},   PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]]. See the large gap at the origin? But joining several lines into one line works.

Separating plot of continuous function into several segments (lines) has no sense to me. It has sense only at discontinuities.

@azerbajdzan Add Exclusions -> None. Or Exclusions -> "Discontinuities". But not Exclusions -> "Singularities". There's supposed to be a gap if using the default setting, which includes singularities.

@MichaelE2 Yes, it works, also CapForm["Butt"] is then redundant. But what is the logic behind it? ArcTan has no discontinuities why would I use Exclusions?

@rhermans I assume the multiple lines comes from packaging the graphics for the GPU to deal with, since the Graphics contains only one Line[]. But yes, that was my idea, to remove the overlaps with CapForm[]. I suppose the community will agree that it's a bug.

@azerbajdzan The singularities of $\arctan()$ at $\pm i$ are treated in Plot as though the plot deserves an exclusion at $x=0$: Trace[Plot[ArcTan[x], {x,-1,1}], _Visualization`ExpandExclusions, TraceInternal->True]. I'm not sure why the exclusions are translated to x == 0. One can check that either of the exclusions generated from the singularities produce a gap with Plot[x, {x,-1,1}, MaxRecursion->1, Exclusions->{{-I+20 x==0,True}(*, {I+20 x==0, True}*)}]. I guess it's a separate bug. (Exclusions -> "Discontinuities" removes singularities from the exclusions.)

@azerbajdzan There's a gap with Plot[ArcTan[20  x], {x, -10, 10},   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]], too. It has nothing to do with the issue at hand. CapForm["Butt"] does fix the issue in the OP with this graph, though (the dark blocks from overlapping segments).

Thanks for the help! This did resolve the issue with my plot, which was a more complicated plot than the one I used as the working example.

I think this is a bug, but there are many workarounds.
It seems to me that the problem is that Mathematica is internally dividing the trace into segments, and the overlapping regions of the thick semi-transparent lines show darker.
While I can not reproduce the problem with your exact code, in Wolfram Cloud I can see the problem with
Plot[
  x^3.
  , {x,-1.,1.}
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]
]


More clearly also if using FullForm as suggested by @azerbajdzan
ListPlot@Cases[
   FullForm[Plot[x^3.,{x,-1.,1.}]]
   , Line[x_]:>x
   , All
]


As I wrote in the comments,  I have seen that as an annoying feature when exporting plots as vector graphics formats like SVG or PDF, where for no real reason, plot traces are not part of a single object but an arbitrary set of ungrouped elements.
One possible workaround could be replacing {Directive[...],Line[...],Line[...]}  with joined lines {Directive[...],Line[...]} 
Plot[
  x^3.
  , {x,-1.,1.}
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]
] /. {a_,Line[b_], Line[c_]}:>{a,Line[Join[b,c]]}


I'm not very good with patterns, but of there are many artifacts, something like this might work
Plot[
  x^3.
  , {x,-1.,1.}
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.03]]
]/. {a_Directive,b___}:>{a,Line[Flatten[{b}[[All,1]],1]]}

If the separation is caused by Exclusions, an alternative solution  could be to use the option  Exclusions->None

This bug with your code can be reproduced also in version 13.0.1.

Hi rhermans - thanks for the help! Interesting insights - unfortunately the workaround doesn't seem to work on my machine - when I run your code I have a line with 4 artifacts. What is interesting is on my machine when I run my original example with FullForm as you do I only get one line back, rather than two. When I  run your example however I do get two lines.

@JamesVR if you have more artefacts, then the ReplaceAll (/. pattern should be different, mine works only for two, but is easier to understand.  Probably somebody else can volunteer a pattern that will work for any number of lines.

@JamesVR see the update

@rhermans I did try varying the replace pattern to match the number of artifacts but no luck - I think ther might be two separate bugs going on, as in FullForm of my example I didn't see two different lines.

@JamesVR It is also possible to have two lines (or more) wrapped in a single Line like for example Graphics[Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}}]] which is equivalent of Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]}].

@JamesVR, azerbajdzan's comment makes a good point. I can only see the artefacts that I can generate, I can't tell if your particular case produces a different internal structure, and many structures are possible. Probably you can ask a new question where you actually show a few examples of the Graphics objects you have, so we can work out a way to merge all the segments into a single Line
